# Biggest Little Polyhedron

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, open-problem, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

The [Biggest Little Polygon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BiggestLittlePolygon.html) problem asks for the polygon with greatest area where the largest diameter is 1.  Let's add a dimension and find the largest volumes.

What is the biggest little polyhedron that can fill space?

What is the biggest little hexahedron?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NEW -- I've posted [Biggest Little Polyhedron—New Solutions in Combinatorial Geometry](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/05/20/biggest-little-polyhedronnew-solutions-in-combinatorial-geometry/), which has a write up of many solutions.

Mathematica 10 allows Volume[ConvexHullMesh[points]], so I took a stab at the problem with annealling at [biggest little polyhedron](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/463699?p_p_auth=Daas8oEC).  In the image below, the red lines indicate a distance of 1.

None of these solutions are exact or perfected, and annealling is vulnerable to local maxima, so I expect improvements on all of these.

[image]

Comment: Can we get rotating versions? It's hard to tell what the shape is just from images.

Comment: The Mathematica notebook is at the Community link.